# The delegate function is broken in this code. What should I do to fix it?

Tags: swift, speech-recognition, appkit

I cannot get this code to work inside of Xcode.  I even set the plist to work with the Microphone Usage and Speech Recognition Usage but it still doesn't work after clean and build with run.

I have looked at many examples and all of them do it the exact same way.

```swift
    import Cocoa  
    import Foundation  
    import AppKit  

    class ViewController: NSViewController, NSSpeechRecognizerDelegate {  

        var speechRec: NSSpeechRecognizer = NSSpeechRecognizer()!  
        var commands = ["a","b","c","d","stop","go"]  

        override func viewDidLoad() {  
            super.viewDidLoad()  
            speechRec.commands = commands  
            speechRec.delegate = self  
            //speechRec.listensInForegroundOnly = true  
            //speechRec.blocksOtherRecognizers = true  
            speechRec.startListening()  
        }  

        override var representedObject: Any? {  
            didSet {  
            // Update the view, if already loaded.  
            }  
        }  

        @IBAction func Listen(_ sender: Any) {  
            speechRec.startListening()  
            print("Listening now...")  
        }  

        @IBAction func Stop(_ sender: Any) {  
            speechRec.stopListening()  
            print("Stopped Listening...")  
        }  

        func speechRecognizer(_ sender: NSSpeechRecognizer, didRecognizeCommand command: String) {  

            print("Recognized...")  

            if (command as String == "a") {  
                print("You picked \(command)")              // Debug print  
            }  
            else if (command as String == "b") {  
                print("You picked \(command)")              // Debug print  
            }  
            else if (command as String == "c") {  
                print("You picked \(command)")              // Debug print  
            }  
            else if (command as String == "d") {  
                print("You picked \(command)")              // Debug print  
            }  
            else if (command as String == "stop") {  
                print("You picked \(command)")              // Debug print  
            }  
            else if (command as String == "go") {  
                print("You picked \(command)")              // Debug print  
            }  
            else {  
                print("You picked \(command)")  
            }  
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully use your code in an empty Cocoa project to detect speech. It built and ran successfully and the delegate methods were called when speech commands were detected.

- To use the AppKit Speech Library I had to download a 1GB SpeechKit Library (XCode  10.2.1 prompted me when I tried to run the app the first time). Have you downloaded the required library?
- Is your microphone properly configured to be the 'Input' source in the Sound Settings panel of System Preferences?
- Turning off App Sandbox allowed direct access to the microphone. Does it work if you turn off App Sandbox?